# How to check the greatest number in table in SQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I was just wondering that, how to get the greatest number in the table.
I mean i have a table called: hits; in that their are 2 columns:
1. id
2. hit

and their are many ids in the table and all have more than 10 hits, now what i want to do is to get the greatest id of the greatest hit
PS: See below:

```
 id | hit
 ---|----
  1 | 10
  2 | 15
  3 | 45
  4 | 9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Id,
       Max(Hit)
       from tableName
       group by id 
       having Max(hit)=(Select Max(Hit) from TableName)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96209/1)

Comment: Thanks!..after adding the question is remembered the MAX and MIN functions!

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use `MAX function` to use like below

```
Select Id,Max(hit) from yourtableName group by id having hit=Max(hit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be faster to do this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 ORDER BY hit DESC, id DESC LIMIT 1`

Rather than using `MAX`, Especially if you have a larger table

http://www.witti.ws/blog/2011/04/06/mysqls-max-slow-5-years-later